# Join no banco de dados

Tags: php, sql, join

Estou desenvolvendo um software onde o usuário seleciona os itens de sua casa, seleciona quanto tempo não os limpa, e no final preenche um formulário para receber um desconto por e-mail e limpar os itens. Todos esses dados vão para o banco.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ao fazer o inner join para exibir no front end, o item cadastrado só reconhece o primeiro ID (no caso, o id 1)[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso resolver isso? minha tbl_item é:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código sql é:

```
SELECT email_cadastrado, nome_cadastrado, nome_item, descricao
FROM tbl_cadastrados c
JOIN tbl_item i ON c.item_cadastrado = i.id_item
JOIN status_cadastrado cad ON c.status_cadastrado = cad.id
where cad.id = 0"
```

Comment: João, o JOIN não vai percorrer seu campo (1,3,4)... O erro provavelmente está no seu loop de criação da tabela. Poste para vermos como está gerando a tabela.

Comment: Adiantando antes de ver, provavelmente você terá um loop para tratar os itens dentro do loop que gera a tabela.

Comment: Use essa função: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php

Comment: @RaoniBZ Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\quiz_Acaro\etapa2.php on line 11

Comment: eu estou tratando a variável assim: $checkBoxValue = join(", ", $_POST['item']);
$_SESSION['item'] = $checkBoxValue;

Comment: Não dá pra entender com pedaços assim. Como o Luiz disse na resposta, está errado a relação, mas dá para fazer dessa outra forma também, precisa ver o que você acha mais fácil. Quebrando o campo e trazendo nomenclatura ou se faz relação de 1 para 1. Acho melhor postar tudo como está, aí o pessoal te passa formas de fazer.

Answer (score 2):

Seu relacionamento esta errado, o campos da sua tabela "item_cadastrado" não deve ser assim, ele deve ser um relação N para N com a tabela de itens, tendo uma tabela intermediaria entre eles, que possuiria os dois valores id_cadastro e id item, assim seu join passaria por eles.

Você precisa reestruturar seu banco colocando esta tabela relacional

**Relacionamento N para N**

N:N – O relacionamento N:N (muitos-para-muitos) possui uma característica diferente dos outros. Neste caso, os dados estão diretamente relacionados ao fato, e não as entidades, como observamos nos outros tipos de relacionamentos vistos anteriormente.

Importante destacar que podem não haver associação de fatos nas situações em que os relacionamentos são de caráter condicional. Neste caso, a cardinalidade deve ser determinada por meio de uma ampla análise quanto à possibilidade de ocorrerem relacionamentos.

Regras de Relacionamento N:N – Para estabelecer este tipo de relacionamento, devemos ter três tabelas, sendo que a terceira é responsável por relacionar as outras duas. Para isso, é preciso que essas duas primeiras tabelas contenham uma coluna que seja chave primária.

As colunas que são chaves primárias na primeira e na segunda tabela devem ser colunas com chave estrangeira na terceira. Assim, esta tabela terá duas chaves estrangeiras, as quais formam uma chave primária composta.